# A body of mass 2 kilograms moves on a circle of radius 2 meters, making one revolution every 5 seconds. Find the centripetal force acting on the body.

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics

My problem is as follows: A body of mass 2 kilograms moves on a circle of radius 2 meters, making one revolution every 5 seconds. Find the centripetal force acting on the body.

What I tried originally was $F_c=\frac{mv^2}{r}$, where $v=\frac{4\pi}{5sec}$, $m=2kg$ and $r=2$, but the program didn't accept the answer I got ($6.3165N$). I then tried what I saw [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100716111848AAdQsO4), but I didn't understand what "t" was in his equations.

I also found this [here](http://www.slader.com/textbook/9781429215084-vector-calculus-sixth-edition/227/exercises/17/), which is the problem from my textbook. Unfortunately, I don't have the answer key for it, so I cannot see what the correct answer is. Apparently, this guy's work is incorrect, but the person who states so didn't post the corrected version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I'm not quite sure what else to try.

Comment: Shouldn't $v= \frac{4\pi}{5}$ not $\frac{8\pi}{5}$ as you've written it?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$F_c=mr\omega^2$$
with
$$\omega=\frac {v}{r}=\frac {d\theta}{dt}=\frac {2\pi}{5} $$

which gives
$$F_c=\frac {16}{25}\pi^2\approx 6.3 N $$

Comment: It doesn't accept 6.3N. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @TobyTobyo  This answer is correct, as your own calculation shows.